After cutting text, and then copying another text, the cut text is prepended to the copied text upon pasting
I cut text in Emacs using control+w. Then I copy another text by highlighting it with a mouse. Finally, I try to paste the copied text using mouse middle click. I expect only the copied text to be pasted. Instead, both the cut and the copied texts are pasted together.
Example:
Starting with this:
<delete this>

<copy and paste this below>

I end up with this:
<copy and paste this below><delete this><copy and paste this below>

But I expected that the cut text will not be present (this is the desired behavior):
<copy and paste this below><copy and paste this below>

I am using Emacs Version 29.4-1 downloaded from GNU Emacs For Mac OS X, running on MacBook Pro with Apple M1 Max chip, macOS Sonoma 14.6.1.
Notes

I am currently using the following workaround to paste only the copied text. After cutting the text with control+w, I highlight any region (even a single character will suffice). I then highlight to copy the desired text. I then click the middle mouse button to paste only the copied text.
The cut and copied text from Emacs are joined together in the system clipboard. That is, if I try to paste the text highlighted in Emacs with command+v into another application, the cut and copied text are pasted together as shown above.


Sounds like you've customized mouse-drag-copy-region to t:

mouse-drag-copy-region is a variable defined in mouse3.el.
Its value is t
Original value was nil
Documentation:
If non-nil, copy to kill-ring upon mouse adjustments of the region.
This affects mouse-save-then-kill (M-x mouse-save-then-kill) in
addition to mouse drags.
You can customize this variable.
This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
version 24.1 of Emacs.


You are right, I have (setq mouse-drag-copy-region t) in my ~/.emacs file. So I tried to delete this line, or to use (setq mouse-drag-copy-region nil) instead. In either case, I then can no longer highlight text to copy it, which is the desired behavior. Is there a method to stop the behavior I described in my question, but at the same time keep this desired behavior: highlight text to copy, middle mouse click to paste? Thank you!

Here os the set of 3 relevant lines in ~/.emacs that I use for customize copy/paste behavior. They used to work for the purpose I described (in the older versions of Emacs): (setq select-active-regions nil)
(setq mouse-drag-copy-region t)
(global-set-key [mouse-2] 'mouse-yank-at-click)

I solved the issue by removing all of these lines from ~/.emacs file: (setq select-active-regions nil) , (setq mouse-drag-copy-region t) , (global-set-key [mouse-2] 'mouse-yank-at-click) . That, however, broke the functionality of easy copying and pasting between emacs and other mac apps. I will ask a separate question about this.
